# How do I add data to current user's UID in Firestore? (Swift, iOS)

Tags: swift, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-authentication

Currently this is what I have and am getting "Cannot find 'UserID' in scope" error

```
@IBAction func mentorTapped(_ sender: Any) {
    
    
    let db = Firestore.firestore()
    
    let userID = Auth.auth().currentUser?.uid
      
    
    db.collection("users").document(UserID).setData(["Add" : "Mentor"], merge: true)
   
}
```

Comment: You have a different case for UserID and userID, which is why it's giving you this error.

Answer (score 1):

You are assigning `userID` with a lowercase 'u':

```
let userID = Auth.auth().currentUser?.uid
```

But you are later trying to use `UserID` with a capital 'U':

```
db.collection("users").document(UserID).setData(["Add" : "Mentor"], merge: true)
```

They are not the same.  Case matters.

Comment: thanks for your reply. I fixed that but am now getting the following error "Value of optional type 'String?' must be unwrapped to a value of type 'String'" next to the db.collection line.

Comment: try unwrapping userID then via db.collection("users").document(userID!).setData(["Add" : "Mentor"], merge: true)

This isn't really a safe way of doing this so I'd suggest you read up on swift optionals

Comment: If you have a second problem, you should post that separately.  It sounds unrelated to the one you first posted.